# return instruction stop my for-loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

when i use a for-loop there is no problem in

```
for (var h = 0; h < xt.length; h++) {
  var heart = '';
  console.log(xt[h]);
  if (row[0] == xt[h]) {
    heart = 'icon-heart';
  } else {
    heart = 'icon-    heart1';
  }
}
```

but when i use return instruction the loop stop :

```
for (var h = 0; h < xt.length; h++) {
  var heart = '';
  console.log(xt[h]);
  if (row[0] == xt[h]) {
    heart = 'icon-heart';
  } else {
    heart = 'icon-heart1';
  }
  return '<i class="' + heart + '" onClick="addFAv(this)"  data-id="' + row[0] + '" data-name="' + row[1] + '"></i> <a href="#" class="icon-line-clipboard i-circled i-small"></a> <a href="#" class="icon-file-alt2 i-circled i-small"></a>';
}
```

Do you know why ?

the whole code  in the function is

```
$('#recevabilite').dataTable({
      "scrollY": "200px",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "paging": false,
      stateSave: true,
      "dom": '<"#recev.top">irt',
      "columnDefs": [{
            "visible": false,
            "targets": [3]
          },
          {
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                //    var date1 = new Date()+10J;
                //affichage des icones  
                var x = localStorage.getItem("listeFavoris");
                xt = x.split(',');

                for (var h = 0; h < xt.length; h++) {
                  var heart = '';
                  console.log(xt[h]);
                  if (row[0] == xt[h]) {
                    heart = 'icon-heart';
                  } else {
                    heart = 'icon-heart1';
                  }
                  return '<i class="' + heart + '" onClick="addFAv(this)"  data-id="' + row[0] + '" data-name="' + row[1] + '"></i> <a href="#" class="icon-line-clipboard i-circled i-small"></a> <a href="#" class="icon-file-alt2 i-circled i-small"></a>';
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: `return` only makes sense inside a function. What do you expect the `return` to do here?

Comment: The case you have described is specifically utilized to return a value (which takes priority over the loop) to the calling function. It's like the pseudocode: `for (seconds in time) { write_code(); if( end_of_day) return home; }`. Do you expect to keep writing code after the end of the day?

Comment: my code is inside a function that add content in cell table (datatable script)

Comment: instead of returning that string within your for loop, add it to an accumulator variable and return that at the end of the function.

Comment: Can you give me an exemple of accumulator variable ?

Comment: Your whole code is missing some `}`

Comment: `return` terminates the function. If you do it in a loop, the loop ends because the function is no longer running.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `return`, it ends the function, so you don't execute any further iterations of the loop.

You need to concatenate the value from each loop iteration, and then return the final result after the loop:

```
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                //    var date1 = new Date()+10J;
                //affichage des icones  
                var x = localStorage.getItem("listeFavoris");
                var xt = x.split(',');
                var html = '';
                for (var h = 0; h < xt.length; h++) {
                  var heart = '';
                  console.log(xt[h]);
                  if (row[0] == xt[h]) {
                    heart = 'icon-heart';
                  } else {
                    heart = 'icon-heart1';
                  }
                  html += '<i class="' + heart + '" onClick="addFAv(this)"  data-id="' + row[0] + '" data-name="' + row[1] + '"></i> <a href="#" class="icon-line-clipboard i-circled i-small"></a> <a href="#" class="icon-file-alt2 i-circled i-small"></a>';
                }
              return html;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks i understand the work but in fact that doesn't work because i need a value for each render function but not a concatenation of al

Comment: Why do you need a loop at all? The render function is called separately for each cell, it should just return the HTML for one cell.

Comment: yes sure i need once per cell but that don't work i have only one good match

Answer (score 0):

i 'va found the solution

```
  {"render": function(data, type, row) {
            //    var date1 = new Date()+10J;
            //affichage des icones  
            var x = localStorage.getItem("listeFavoris");
            var xt = x.split(',');
            var html = '<a href="#" class="icon-line-clipboard i-circled i-small"></a> <a href="#" class="icon-file-alt2 i-circled i-small"></a>';
            for (var h = 0; h < xt.length; h++) {
              var heart = '';
              console.log(xt[h]);
              if (row[0] == xt[h]) {
                heart = 'icon-heart';
                  h = xt.length; }
              html += '<i class="' + heart + '" onClick="addFAv(this)"  data-id="' + row[0] + '" data-name="' + row[1] + '"></i>';
            }
        if   (heart == '') {
        html += '<i class="icon-heart1" onClick="addFAv(this)"  data-id="' + row[0] + '" data-name="' + row[1] + '"></i>';}
          return html;

        }, "targets": 4}
```